# Android: getActivity() null when calling it from the ViewModel as a callback

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, callback, android-viewmodel

I have my project set up with DataBinding, so the RecyclerView Item gets clicked, the ViewModel of the Fragment gets the data and needs to change the Fragment. So I created a callback that is implmented in the Fragment itself to change it but when it gets called, the getActivity() function (or "activity?" as written below) is null.

**Callback Interface**

```
interface FragmentCallBack {
    fun fragmentCallBack(object: Object?)
}
```

**Fragment**

```
class MainFragment : Fragment(), FragmentCallBack {
    override fun fragmentCallBack(object: Object?) {
        val fragment = NewFragment.newInstance()
        // Here is the issue <------------------------
        activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.container, fragment)?.commit()
    }
}
```

**Fragment ViewModel**

```
class FragmentViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val callback: FragmentCallBack = MainFragment()

    private fun getData(string: String) {
        val liveData = Repository.getData(string)
        callback.fragmentCallBack(liveData.value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You manually construct MainFragment in the ViewModel, without properly adding it to any container. In this situation, it isn't associated with any Activity, so NPE is the expected outcome.

There are several problems with this code:

- Fragments should be added into containers. The best way to do that is to use some Fragment management library
- ViewModel's shouldn't "know" anything about Fragments
- Invoking methods on Fragments from outside (e.g. `fragmentCallback`) is always a recipe for problems
- [Best practice] If you have a method called `getData`, invoking callback that results in navigation might not be the best design. That's not what the name suggests and naming is important.

To be frank, this code suggests that you aren't very experienced with Fragments and ViewModels, so I'd recommend going over the documentation. Otherwise, working with these two complex APIs might result in many problems and much frustration.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what fragments are and how viewmodels are supposed to be isolated. I am just learning how to setup databinding to skip the boiler plate code in the View.

The issue I came across was that since I am no longer writing code in the fragment itself, since the databinding results go directly into the viewModel, I need a way to change the fragment from the viewModel when the user taps on an item.